# Max length for select multiple in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a select multiple field in angular and I want to limit the total number of options a person can choose. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4A8b7/1/

The gist of it looks like this:

```
<select size="10" id="myselection"
    ng-multiple="true" ng-model="selectedColors" 
    ng-options="c.name+' ('+c.shade+')' for c in colors" ng-maxlength="2" 
    required>
</select>
```

The form never evaluates length for validity, the only time the form is invalid is when there are no options selected. I am not sure if maxlength is "supposed" to work with select, but if its not, how can I extend the directive to make it work with select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-maxlength` is for input length, and `ng-multiple` is [not supported anymore](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/45affbef93ab6cb645f8e9a68402af93aa3929b4).  You can watch the length of the `selectedColors` array, and call `$setValidity` manually.

```
$scope.$watch('selectedColors.length', function(length) {        
    var valid = length <= 2;
    $scope.form.colors.$setValidity("max2", valid);
});
```

Then you can use the validity in the view like so:

```
<form name="form">
<select name="colors" ... ></select>
<span ng-show="form.colors.$error.max2">Only select up to 2 colors.</span>
```

If you want to try the code, [here is an update of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39WK6/1/).